# undefined index error occurs when trying to delete a session from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to delete a session from a drop down menu. The user will select a session from the drop down menu and then click on the delete button, this should then delete session in the database. The problem is that if I click on the delete button, it then comes up with an undefined index errors stating `sessionsDrop` are undefined in line 200 My question is:

1: How can I get rid of the undefined index error in code below
2: How and where do you write the if statement so that if the deletion was successful, it will echo "Session ... was Deleted" else if it hasn't been delete then display echo "An error occured, Session ... was not deleted"

Below is the code:

```
$sessionnum = 0;

 if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

     if($_REQUEST['modulesDrop']==''){

         echo "Please Select a Module from the Drop Down Menu Above";

     }
     else{  

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; 
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;

}

   $sessionHTML = "";
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;     

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {

   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        

        }

   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';
}
 if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Delete" name="sessionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}
else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}

}

 if (isset($_POST['sessionsubmit'])) {

     if($_REQUEST['sessionsDrop']==''){ //line 200 where undefined index occurs

         echo "Please Select a Session from the Drop Down Menu Above to Delete a Session";

     }
     else{  

 var_dump($_POST['sessionsDrop']);

 $sessiondel = $_POST['sessionsDrop'];

         $sessiondeletesql = " DELETE sess 
        FROM Session AS sess 
        WHERE sess.SessionId = ?"; 


                if (!$delete = $mysqli->prepare($sessiondeletesql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$delete->bind_param("s", $sessiondel);

 $delete->execute();

        if ($delete->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $delete->close();

        echo "Session $sessiondel was Deleted";
}
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `undefined index` error is because you are using `$_REQUEST['sessionsDrop']==''`, but your form code is -

```
$sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
```

So you should use `$_REQUEST['session']==''`, instead of `$_REQUEST['sessionsDrop']==''` since the super globals (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`) reference the `name`, not the `id`.